# Calling python function from Lua program

Tags: python, lua

I have to call the sum function,sum.py from the lua program main.lua. But I am getting an error.
 The python program:

```
#sum.py
def sum_from_python(a, b):
    return a + b
```

The lua program:

```
#main.lua
py = require 'python'
sum_from_python = py.import "sum".sum_from_python
print( sum_from_python(2,3) )
```

The error :

```
lua: main.lua:1: module 'python' not found:
    no field package.preload['python']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/python.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/python/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/python.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/python/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/python.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/python/init.lua'
    no file './python.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/python.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/python.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/python.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './python.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    main.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I have already installed Lupa. But it doesn't seems to work. Which package should I have to install. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather Lupa is a Python library which allows you to run LUA code in Python, and not the other way around.

If what you want is a module that runs Python code in LUA (and viceversa), you might be interested in [Lunatic Python](https://github.com/bastibe/lunatic-python)

Comment: **Thanks it worked. I am trying to link python program to lua. So is it possible to include import statements in python program?**